# Best library for audio file meta data?

Tags: c++, c, audio, mp3, ogg

I am looking for a library to read meta data from compressed and uncompressed audio files (i.e. mp3, ogg, etc.). In the past I have used libvorbis and id3lib, but I'm wondering if there are better libraries around? Ideally I would like a library that provides a common API to reading meta data from all the various formats. I realize more advanced libraries probably have id3lib and libvorbis as dependencies, and I don't mind that, I just would like to avoid having to write my own wrapper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TagLib](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html) seems like a good candidate.

Comment: or taglib-sharp for c# implementation.

Comment: TagLib has no AAC support, MediaInfo has.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the symbian API, but it seems to do what you wanted, so check this out as well:

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Audio_Metadata_Reader_API